# SSH session - fixed port on the client side

Tags: sockets, unix, ssh

Is it possible to set the fixed port on the client side of the connection?

I connect to the ssh-server using port 22 and the client socket is getting random port to identify the session. An example (output from netstat -atn)

```
tcp4       0      0  <server>.22       <client>.54117    ESTABLISHED
```

In this example, client gets port 54117. For the test purposes, I'd like a fixed port to be assigned for the client, let's say 40185.

So I'd love the following output:

```
tcp4       0      0  <server>.22       <client>.40185    ESTABLISHED
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: For what purpose? If you have some mad net admin defining fixed outbound ports on the firewall, just ask him why. If it's you, just stop. There's no security in it.

Comment: One script uses netstat output to check if the server is already using particular port. But the developer hasn't noticed, that in the output are mentioned client ports as well. I know how to fix the script, but I'd like to reproduce that particular case .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programmaticaly, but the **ssh(1)** command doesn't allow to do that.  The main reason is that you let the kernel select the client port, so you can open more than one **ssh(1)** session to the same server from different source ports in the same client machine.  If you fix the port number in the client and the server, you cannot distinguish the packets belonging to one connection from the ones belonging to the other (same protocol, tcp, same source address, same dest address, same source port and same destination port)

To do it programmaticaly in a client and fix the local port, just call **bind(2)** system call to fix it, before doing the **connect(2)** system call (as the server does just before the **accept(2)** system call)

Be careful in that you cannot have two connections with the same five parameters (*source add*, *source port*, *tcp protocol*, *dest port*, *dest addr*)

Comment: This cannot be the accepted answer. It does not show anything about how to use that `bind` and `connect`.

Comment: @tash, bind and connect are documented in the programmers' manual (as system calls they are, this is in section 2 of the online reference manual), so I preferred to provide links to the man pages to visit, than to copy and reproduce them here.  By the way, I direct the asker to the correct place to look for the documentation, correctly, and, not having access to the operating system in use by the asker, I prefer just to direct him there, than to copy/paste my local documentation (that can be different than the one in his/her system).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround:
(Credited to https://serverfault.com/a/920028)

> ssh -o 'ProxyCommand nc -p 12345 %h %p' user@some.host.org