# How to set ssh-client port

Tags: ssh

My quession is like the follow

> [SSH session - fixed port on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481400/ssh-session-fixed-port-on-the-client-side)

Is there any solution to use like `tcp-client:1234 ------> tcp-server-ssh:22`

Comment: What's wrong with the answer on the [question that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481400/ssh-session-fixed-port-on-the-client-side)?

Comment: Do you understand that you would be able to make single such connection ? You can patch ssh client (extend existing **-b** option) but whole idea does not make any sense (and this is the reason for downvotes).

Comment: ok, I want to do this just because of the fire wall, I can only use  fix port in my computer

Answer (score 0):

I have fix it to compile [openssh](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable),I use version `openssh-portable-V_8_3_P1`

1. add `int  options.bind_port`
2. fix main()

```
char myaddress[100]={};
.....
    case 'b':
        sscanf(optarg,"%[^:]:%d",myaddress,&options.bind_port);         
        options.bind_address = myaddress;
        break;
```

3. fix `sshconnect.c` at line`430`

```
    ((struct sockaddr_in*)&bindaddr)->sin_port= htons(options.bind_port);
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&bindaddr, bindaddrlen) != 0) {
        error("bind %s: %s", ntop, strerror(errno));
        goto fail;
    }
```

4. ./configure && make
5. ln -s .ssh  .myssh
6. try

```
./myssh  -b 192.168.1.153:5566  root@xxx.xyz
```

7. then  you can see

```
vmuser@ubuntu:~$ lsof | grep "myssh.*TCP"
myssh     110179                 vmuser    3u     IPv4            4018314      0t0        TCP ubuntu:5566->myother_ubuntu:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
myssh     110187                 vmuser    3u     IPv4            4017137      0t0        TCP ubuntu:5588->myother_ubuntu:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
```